# Posting screenshot through Facebook SDK for Unity

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, screenshot

I have a problem with posting screenshot to FB. Connection is not the problem because I collect, deserialize and show my fb data. Post score and message to friend work fine but I cannot manage to post a shot from my phone. I am using Eclipse for debugging but I don't get any errors. My code look like this:
`

```
IEnumerator TakeScreenShot()
{    
        //coroutine because I want to wait until end of the frame for shot
   yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    //create new texture that will be my screenshot
      Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(Screen.width,Screen.height,TextureFormat.RGB24, false); 
        // read pixels from screen
       tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0,0,Screen.width,Screen.height),0,0); 
        //and apply them to texture
      tex.Apply(); 
        // now we have screenshot
        // now we need to encode texture to array of bytes
       byte[] buffer = tex.EncodeToPNG();
    //so we can save it to storage 
    // System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/screenshots/screen/screen" + ".png", buffer);  
        //or to convert it to string for posting to facebook
       string s = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
        //????? maybe my string format is not correct
       var query = new Dictionary<string, string>();
       query["photos"] = s;
       FB.API("me?fields=photos",Facebook.HttpMethod.POST, delegate (string r) { ;     }, query);
        }
```

`
when I go to GraphExplorer and paste command "me?fields=photos" I get nothing. It means function did nothing. I forgot to say that i granted permission for user_photos. This is frustrating. I have lost three days on problem that looked trivial, and yet no solution in sight. I will appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Right now there's no easy way to handle this through FB.API since it takes in a `Dictionary<string, string>`.

However `FB.API()` is really just a wrapper around Unity's `WWW` class.  You can call the graph endpoints at [graph.facebook.com](http://graph.facebook.com) and pass in the `byte[] buffer = tex.EncodeToPNG()` as a param in `WWWForm()`.

UPDATE: `FB.API()` has been updated in version 4.3.3 to support `WWWForm` as well.  You can now upload photos via that method now.